# Delay CSS function in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, delay

How can I delay a CSS change in jquery? Here is my code:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".pressimage img").mouseenter(function() {
        $jq(this).css('z-index','1000');
            });
    $(".pressimage img").mouseleave(1000,function() {
        $jq(this).css('z-index','1');
            });
});
```

I need the mouseleave function to occur about 1/2 a second after the mouse leaves.

Im using some other jquery to make images expand on mouseover. When they expand they cover each other, so I need the z-index of the animated image to be higher than the other. Then when the mouse leaves the z-index has to return to normal.

The above code works except that the z-index changes as soon as the mouse leaves, so the animation doesn't have time to complete. I therefore need to delay the mouseleave function a bit. Thanks

UPDATE

Here is my site:
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/ppr6/press

Ive put my code in the head:

```
 $jq("document").ready(function() {

    $jq(".pressimage img").mouseenter(function() {
        $jq(this).css('z-index','100');
            });

    $jq(".pressimage img").mouseleave(function() {
        $jq(this).css('z-index','1');
            });

});
```

This code is working fine but doesn't have any delay. If you hover over the top left image it works fine but as soon as you mouse off it goes behind the image below it.
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".pressimage img").mouseleave( function(){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout( function(){
      $(that).css('z-index','1');
    },500);
 });
```

Answer (score 14):

Delay only works on items in the queue so you need to add your css change to the queue for the delay to work.  Then dequeue. The following code illustrates this:

```
$('.pressimage img')
    .delay(1000)
    .queue(function(){
        $(this).css({'z-index','1'});
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that sanon's solution above is more natural than this one because it uses jQuery's `.queue` method instead of abusing `.animate` for the same purpose.

Original answer below:

---

setTimeout is the most natural way to go, but if you want to stay in your jQuery function chain, you can use an animate function with duration 0.

Example:

```
$("img").delay(1000).animate({'z-index': 1000},0)
```

If you want to do anything else than numeric css changes, then you do need to create a function, but that can still happen within that animate call:

```
$("img").delay(1000).animate({zoom:1},0,function(){$(this).src('otherImage.png');})
```

I'm just putting that zoom:1 there because if you specify an empty object {} there, it is not considered a real effect, so doesn't go on the effects queue, so immediately executes the complete function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with setTimeout();

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var timer;
    $(".pressimage img").mouseenter(function() {
        $jq(this).css('z-index','1000');
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });
    $(".pressimage img").mouseleave(1000,function() {
         timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $jq(this).css('z-index','1');
         }, 500);
    });
});
```

The code in setTimeout(code, delay) executes after *delay* milliseconds.  You might have problems with unintended changes if you were to move the mouse about too quickly, so I have cleared the timeout action on mouseenter().

Comment: your method works for a few hovers but then stops working. Just like Loktar's.

Comment: I added a clearTimeout() in there to stop the set timeout in the event of rapid mouse enter/leave events.  It should make it work better, at least.

Comment: When I hover over the image the z-index is changed to 1000 but then on mouseleave it doesn't change back to 1. Thanks

Comment: I must have a typo or something.  I see you have a working solution so +1 to that guy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("document").ready(function() {
$(".pressimage img").mouseenter(function() {
    $jq(this).css('z-index','1000');
        });
$(".pressimage img").mouseleave(1000,function() {
    $jq(this).delay(500).css('z-index','1');
        });
});
```

Does this work? :)

Comment: Thats to bad :( But fortunately the above answers should work :)

Comment: Ok, ill look into it more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/yK5ga/

Check that one out what I am doing is assigning the timeout to a variable and then clearing it on mouseover, so it wont fire if you do a mouse over quickly.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var imgTimeout;

    $("img").hover(
        function() {
            clearTimeout(imgTimeout);
            $(this).css('z-index','1000');
    },
    function() {
        var element = $(this);
        imgTimeout = setTimeout(function(){element.css('z-index','1');}, 1000); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Weird.. Ill jsfiddle it unless someone comes up with a better/different answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Seems like it should though. Ill have a play around and upload a version to show if necessary. Thanks

Comment: Ive had a closer look. The problem when I use your code is that one of the images (the bottom left one in my link) works initially but then keeps the z-index of 1000 when it should revert to 1. The same thing is happening with some of the other solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    qcss: function(map){
        $(this).queue(function(next){ 
            $(this).css(map); 
            next(); 
        });

        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/delay-css

tested and working for my purpose of delaying a css property following an animate.